# Which object should take care of loading a new window?

Tags: macos, swift2

Basically what the title says. Should it be initial window's controller, or some other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fair number of windows that interact with each other and need a coordinator, I would suggest to create your own `WindowManager` class to handle this interaction. There you can put the logic of creating them and some of the communication between them if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It should be created inside the `xib` as it will be loaded and bound to It's IBOutlets and IBActions on launch. However, It can be created programatically in the `AppDelegate` inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching` or any other place really.

Comment: I meant what is best practice for calling a new window. I know how to design them.

Comment: No. I mean, if I have application with several windows, which class generally should take care of opening them?